# Каким членом предложения является слово "тебе" в этом предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, местоимения, члены-предложения

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
"**Тебе** ни о чем не нужно мне  рассказывать".

Тебе - подлежащее или дополнение? Почему?

Если заменить на "**ты** ни о чём мне не рассказываешь", видится, что "ты" - подлежащее.

Comment: По смыслу логичнее заменить на "Ты ни о чём не должен рассказывать".

Comment: В тексте именно "тебе", и стоит задача определить ЧП..

Comment: Исправила вариант.

Comment: А зачем вы добавили "мне"? Я сказал, что замена по смыслу не равноценная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Тебе ни о чем не нужно мне рассказывать*.

Односоставное безличное предложение, подлежащего нет и быть не может, сказуемое *не нужно рассказывать* - составное глагольное. Оно и есть грамматическая основа. **Кому не нужно** рассказывать? Тебе - дополнение.

*Ты ни о чём мне не рассказываешь* - двусоставное предложение. Кто? Ты. Что делаешь? Не рассказываешь. Основа - *ты не рассказываешь*. Это совсем другое предложение. Не стоит трансформировать предложение, чтобы найти основу, её нужно искать в том  предложении, которое дано.